# Stanford cs193p Fall 2011 course made a mistake in lecture 9?

Tags: ios, cs193p

In lecture 9, the teacher said that numberOfSectionsInTableView: method returns 1 by default, but when I created my own project, I found that it returns 0 by default, and that made my table view cell disappeared! I found where the problem was and fixed it by making the numberOfSectionsInTableView: return 1, problem gone. So, that means Stanford made a mistake?

When I added a new subclass of UITableViewController, in the .m file, Xcode generated the following code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using Xcode 4.3.3 by the way...

Comment: Have code (of both)? There is no "default return value" in C or Obj-C.

Comment: There are no infallible people.

Comment: - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}

Answer (score 6):

You misunderstood what the default value means. When apple or a teacher or someone mentions that the default return value for a method is something then it means that whenever that method is NOT implemented it will behave in this way.

When you wrote your own method you returned a value of 0. IF you use the template then that template is overwriting the method to set it to 0. If you want the default behavior just delete the method.

These kind of delegate methods do have default values most of the time. Control click on the Delegate implementation on the header file and you will see the @Optional methods which are methods that have default values most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

I believe by “default” they mean, if your `UITableViewDataSource` does not implement `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` then a value of 1 is assumed. The Xcode template may include the above code (returning 0), but that’s not the same as the framework’s default.

Comment: So I should just delete the code above, and then problem gone? Pretty simple.Thanks!

Comment: Yep, but it’s usually nice to be explicit about things like this in code.

Answer (score 0):

Our Standford friend is right I'm afraid. The default is 1. I rarely include this method. Just to be sure, I tested it by removing the method from the app I'm working on, and sure enough, only 1 section. I've developed apps from version 1.0 to the current version.

Make sure your delegate is set to the right class. And make sure your xib has the right class name for the file owner. That one gets me once in a while.